# How to correctly set height in TextField in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So I have this textfield,

```
var value = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

OutlinedTextField(
    value = value.value,
    placeholder = {
        Text("Search Users")
    },
    singleLine = true,
    modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp),
    onValueChange = {
        value.value = it
    },
)
```

I am setting height to `40.dp` as you can see. However it looks like this,

[image]

Looks like the text/placeholder is cut off. How to fix this?

Comment: You can use `56.dp` or higher.

Comment: I reported this, call it "inflexibility", to Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228928703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the problem is that the font size is too big for the provided height. The correct way to provide a height for the field is using the modifiers as you already are doing. However, to work around this problem either increase the height of the text field or decrease the size of the font.

Answer (score 4):

I run into same problem using OutlinedTextField. Obviously, this is material component that have exact padding, that is causing crop on text (even with smaller font size).

Here is result:

[image: compose custom TextField]

Solution is to use BasicTextField, and here is the code:

```
@Composable
private fun CustomTextField(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
leadingIcon: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = null,
trailingIcon: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = null,
placeholderText: String = "Placeholder",
fontSize: TextUnit = MaterialTheme.typography.body2.fontSize
) {
var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
BasicTextField(modifier = modifier
    .background(
        MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
        MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    )
    .fillMaxWidth(),
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        text = it
    },
    singleLine = true,
    cursorBrush = SolidColor(MaterialTheme.colors.primary),
    textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
        fontSize = fontSize
    ),
    decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
        Row(
            modifier,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            if (leadingIcon != null) leadingIcon()
            Box(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                if (text.isEmpty()) Text(
                    placeholderText,
                    style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
                        color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.3f),
                        fontSize = fontSize
                    )
                )
                innerTextField()
            }
            if (trailingIcon != null) trailingIcon()
        }
    }
)
}
```

calling it with changed background shape:

```
CustomTextField(
        leadingIcon = {
            Icon(
                Icons.Filled.Search,
                null,
                tint = LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = 0.3f)
            )
        },
        trailingIcon = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(
                MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
                RoundedCornerShape(percent = 50)
            )
            .padding(4.dp)
            .height(20.dp),
        fontSize = 10.sp,
        placeholderText = "Search"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using height you can set the minHeight:

```
modifier = Modifier.defaultMinSize(minHeight = 40.dp)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's my material TextField with the ability to change contentPadding. Then you call anywhere.

```
@Composable
fun MyTextField(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    readOnly: Boolean = false,
    textStyle: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
    label: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    placeholder: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    leadingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    trailingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    isError: Boolean = false,
    visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions(),
    singleLine: Boolean = false,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    shape: Shape = TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldShape,
    colors: TextFieldColors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(),
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp, top = 5.dp, bottom = 5.dp)
) {
    // If color is not provided via the text style, use content color as a default
    val textColor = textStyle.color.takeOrElse {
        colors.textColor(enabled).value
    }
    val mergedTextStyle = textStyle.merge(TextStyle(color = textColor))

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
    BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        modifier = modifier
            .background(colors.backgroundColor(enabled).value, shape)
            .indicatorLine(enabled, isError, interactionSource, colors),
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        enabled = enabled,
        readOnly = readOnly,
        textStyle = mergedTextStyle,
        cursorBrush = SolidColor(colors.cursorColor(isError).value),
        visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
        keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
        keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        singleLine = singleLine,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        decorationBox = @Composable { innerTextField ->
            // places leading icon, text field with label and placeholder, trailing icon
            TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
                value = value,
                visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
                innerTextField = innerTextField,
                placeholder = placeholder,
                label = label,
                leadingIcon = leadingIcon,
                trailingIcon = trailingIcon,
                singleLine = singleLine,
                enabled = enabled,
                isError = isError,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                colors = colors,
                contentPadding = contentPadding
            )
        }
    )
}
```